# $(document).height() não retorna o valor correto

Tags: jquery

Estou tentando pegar o tamanho `$(document).height()` do meu site, mas o valor mostrado as vezes é diferente do que o tamanho do HTML (em inspecionar elemento) mostra.

Já tentei chamar diretamente o `$("html").height()`, mas também não funcionou.

Eu encontrei essa [pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21131957/jquery-returns-wrong-document-height) respondida, porém não sei como aplicar a resposta para testar.

Comment: Já tentou as respostas a [essa outra pergunta](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1145850/520779)? Se possível poste seu código - ou talvez um link para seu site - pois sem conhecer sua estrutura fica difícil saber o que pode estar acontecendo. Quando você diz "diferente" você quer dizer bastante diferente (tipo, com implicações práticas) ou só marginalmente diferente (os browsers às vezes calculam os tamanhos de forma ligeiramente diferente)? Por fim, há elementos com altura 100% ou divs com scroll diferente do padrão?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

o $(document).height() pega o valor certo, mas eu estava tentando pegá-lo quando o documento estivesse pronto, que no caso é como o código começa:

$(document).ready(function() {
    alert($(document).height());
});

Mas eu descobri que ao utilizar o $(document).ready, certas informações eram perdidas, já que o mesmo executa quando o html é carregado e o DOM está pronto, então utilizei o $(window).load que executa somente quando toda a página é completamente carregada, incluindo todos os frames, objects e imagens.

Então o código que funciona do jeito que eu queria é o seguinte:

$(window).load(function() {
    var teste = $(document).height();
    alert(teste);
});

Ou seja, quando a página é completamente carregada, o código dispara um alerta com o valor da altura total do documento (html).

Answer (score 0):

Faça assim:

```
$(document).outerHeight()
```

Isso retorna o valor do elemento contando também com o padding